# How to get the x, y coordinates of an element in a web page?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation

I am using Selenium WebDriver and coding in Java. In a code I need to scroll down to a specific element in the web page for clicking it. I am using JavascriptExecutor command. My question is how will I get to know the exact x and y coordinates of that specific element as per the position of it in the web page. The syntax of the code I am using is given below:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(x,y)");
```

In the second line of the above code I need to give the specific values for the x and y coordinates of the element I want to click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to give reference the element itself instead of its coordinates.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To know the exact `x` and `y` coordinates of that specific element as per the pixel position of it in the web page you can consider to use the following code block:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class location_of_element 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        Point point = element.getLocation();
        System.out.println("Element's Position from left side is: "+point.getX()+" pixels.");
        System.out.println("Element's Position from top is: "+point.getY()+" pixels.");
     }
}
```

> Ensure that you have imported `org.openqa.selenium.Point`

The output on your console will be as:

```
Element's Position from left side is: 413 pixels.
Element's Position from top is: 322 pixels.
```

Comment: Many thanks DebanjanB for your contribution. Much appreciations.

Answer (score 2):

You can get coordinates using java selenium,

```
webElement.getLocation().getX();
webElement.getLocation().getY();
```

Answer (score 0):

Santosh is right you should scroll using reference of element. but if still you want to get the coordinates use below code:-

You can use below code:-

```
@Test
 public void getCoordinates() throws Exception {
  //Locate element for which you wants to retrieve x y coordinates.
       WebElement Image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@border='0']"));
       //Used points class to get x and y coordinates of element.
        Point classname = Image.getLocation();
        int xcordi = classname.getX();
        System.out.println("Element's Position from left side"+xcordi +" pixels.");
        int ycordi = classname.getY();
        System.out.println("Element's Position from top"+ycordi +" pixels.");
 }
```

source :-

http://www.maisasolutions.com/blog/How-o-get-X-Y-coordinates-of-element-in-Selenium-WebDriver